# Deleting object from DB in Silverlight 4 RIA (Entities framework)

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I'm developing simple Silverlight 4 application based on one-to-many association.
The model of relation is presented [here.](http://www.image-share.com/upload/1214/135.png)

The page consists of two grids, one is loaded straightly from DomainDataSource (ExcelTemplate one). After selecting *ExcelTemplate* the second one is loaded with ColumnValidationRules from ObservableCollection which is filled on base of *ExcelTemplate*'s list. Entities does not have OnDelete actions. I have a lot of problems with deleting *ColumnValidationRule* objects family. Basically I've tried 2 different approaches:

- Deleting only *ColumnValidationRule* using
  *ColumnValidationRuleDomainDataSource* (based on *GetColumnValidationRule* query):

**XAML with my DomainDataSources:**

```
                                <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my:ExcelTemplate, CreateList=true}" Height="0" LoadedData="ExcelTemplateDomainDataSource_LoadedData" Name="excelTemplatesForValidatiorsDDS" QueryName="GetExcelTemplatesQuery" Width="0">
                                    <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                                        <my1:SRFDomainContext />
                                    </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                                </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

                                <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my:ColumnValidationRule, CreateList=true}" Height="0" LoadedData="ExcelTemplateDomainDataSource_LoadedData" Name="columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetColumnValidationRulesQuery" Width="0">
                                    <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                                        <my1:SRFDomainContext />
                                    </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                                </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

**Code:**

```
     // Filling DataViews:
     this.excelTemplatesForValidatiorsDDS.Load();
     this.columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource.Load();

    // Delete action:
    private void DeleteRuleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource.Load();
        ColumnValidationRule cvr = this.srfValidatorsDataGrid.SelectedItem as ColumnValidationRule;
        this.columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource.DataView.Remove(cvr);
    }
```

In result im getting an error: 
**The specified entity is not contained in this EntitySet.**

**Error details:**

```
w System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntitySet.Remove(Entity entity)
   w System.Windows.Controls.PagedEntityCollectionView.RemoveCore(Entity item, Int32 index)
   w System.Windows.Controls.PagedEntityCollectionView.RemoveItem(Entity item)
   w System.Windows.Controls.EntityCollectionView.Remove(Object item)
   w System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSourceView.Remove(Object item)
   w LANOS.UserManagement.DeleteRuleButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   w System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   w System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   w MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventN
```

---

- Creating different DomainDataSource for each of objects family:
     *ColumnValidationRule*, *AssociatedColumn*, *ColumnValue*. Then deleting them using those DomainDataSource's and submitting from the
     tail to head. This approach also failed. I had similar error to
     those in 1st approach. Also from time to time some of those
     DomainDataSource's were empty.

I was googling after examples which would cover this problem but I have not found any. Appreciating any tips, links or help ;)

---

**UPDATE1:**

I have used your advice:

```
    this.columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource.Load();
    ColumnValidationRule deletedObject = null;

    foreach (ColumnValidationRule cvr in this.columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource.DataView)
    {
        if (cvr.ID.Equals((this.srfValidatorsDataGrid.SelectedItem as ColumnValidationRule).ID))
        {
            deletedObject = cvr;
        }
    }
    this.columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource.DataView.Remove(deletedObject);
    this.columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource.SubmitChanges();
```

Now im getting this error: **The item provided is not instance of type Entity** :/

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I've added on SubmitedChanges Event handler and as I suspected in the beginning of the post, there is a problem with deleting caused by Foreign Keys:

```
e.Error.Message "Submit operation failed. An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. InnerException message: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_AssociatedColumn_ColumnValidationRule\". The conflict occurred in database \"LANOS\", table \"dbo.AssociatedColumns\", column 'ColumnValidationRuleID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to set up model to make use of End On Delete - Cascade property.
Setting Cascade deleting cause compilation error:

```
End 'ColumnValue' on relationship 'LANOSModel.FK_AssociatedColumnColumnValue' cannot have operation specified since its multiplicity is '*'. Operations cannot be specified on ends with multiplicity '*'.
```

Comment: How are you filling your DataViews? According to the error message, you're trying to delete an entity that isn't attached to the context, so maybe you've created a copy of it somewhere? Please post the piece of code in charger of filling your dataviews.

Comment: I've added the code you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason "the specified entity is not contained in this EntitySet" is because.... wait for it... the specified *instance* of that entity *really is not* contained in the EntitySet.

You have apparently loaded the data grid from a previous data context, whereas `this.columnValidationRulesDomainDataSource.Load()` is creating a new set of entities, so you cannot remove your specific old object from a new data set. They have the same values but are not the same objects.

You can however use a key from the object and do a delete on the new context (where the id's match). Just find the matching instance first and delete that.

If you can provide more details/code I might be able to provide a specific example, but you should have enough to go on now.

Comment: Painfully, but Ive managed to fix all problems. Your tip was mostly helpful so thank you for help. Cheers.